# typescript interface syntax for prototyping multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, typescript, typescript1.4

I am trying to add some extension methods for a 2 dimensional array using typescript.

For a 1 dimensional Array the syntax is easy:
e.g.

```
interface Array<T> {
    randomize();  
}
Array.prototype.randomize = function () {
    this.sort(() => (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5));
}
```

I was hoping I could do something similar with a 2 dimensional array, but the following does not work:

```
interface Array<Array<T>> {
    test();
}
```

Is it possible in Typescript to prototye on a 2 dimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any type system mechanism for this. Fundamentally, at runtime, `Array.prototype` either has a `randomize` function or it doesn't. You could write a standalone function that had a constraint, though:

```
function flatten<T extends Array<any>>(arr: T[]): T {
    return null; // TODO implement
}

var x: string[][] = /* ... */;
var y = flatten(x); // y: string[]
var z = flatten(y); // error
```

---

As an aside, you should not use that `randomize` function in earnest. Many sorting algorithms depend on transitivity of ordering (`A > B`, `B > C` implies `A > C`) or stability (`A > B` implies `A > B`), which your function does not preserve. This is at best going to be non-uniform and at worst might crash some runtimes.

Comment: not sure I understand "at runtime Array.prototype either has a randomize or it doesn't".  The following javascript code works to add the extension method to Array:  Array.prototype.randomize = function () {
    this.sort(function () { return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5); });
};  My issue is that I am unable to do something similar for the 2 dimensional case (using typescript).    I am definitely able to use my randomize extension method in the 1d case.  NOTE:  thanks for comment on randomize, actually this was just a lame example not the focus, I should just have called the method test().

Comment: Actally I should add that in Visual studio 2013 in my typeiscript for the 1D case, I see the warning "Extending prototype of native object "Array" may have unexpected side effects", not sure what these side effects may be...